# Problem with msiexec.exe locking up when installing / uninstalling

Tags: windows-server-2008, process, corruption

I am running two virtual 2008 Windows Servers that have been having some reoccurring problems for the past few months. Msiexec.exe seems to run and always freezes at 25% cpu usage and around 12 - 15k memory usage when uninstalling (and perhaps installing) certain applications.

I first noticed this when trying to remove C++ Visual Basic then trying to run a repair utility for it as well... froze at 25%. Tonight I was trying to uninstall Office 2003 from this server and it locked up from the Add / Remove programs method. I then downloaded Microsoft's cleanup utility and on the second step it calls msiexec.exe and it hung at 25% as well!

Here is what I've tried and know -
 - This is happening on both servers.
 - I've ran sfc /scannow nothing found.
 - Ran checkdisk on both servers, nothing found.
 - Scanned for viruses.
 - Removed Anti Virus and tried.
 - Stopped services, msconfig items, and tried booting to a basic config.
 - msi.dll is at 4.5 (latest version without R2 or W7)
 - Tried setting the priority for msiexec.exe from task manager.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag your question with the name of the operating system when asking operating system specific questions. Thank You! (edited to add "windows-server-2008")

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem with Server 2003 with Terminal Services.  `MSIEXEC.EXE` would consume 25% CPU for an unusually long time during install/uninstall, but if we waited it would complete.  Small `.MSI` packages which should have taken seconds to install were taking 15 or 20 minutes.  We found the problem was `NTUSER.DAT` bloat and registry keys from Hewlett Packard printers.  We used the following procedure from http://www.brianmadden.com/forums/t/12621.aspx to resolve the issue:

1. Delete the following keys:

   - `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install\Software\hewlett-packard`
   - `HKU\.Default\Software\Hewlett-Packard`
2. Then delete all the user profiles so they will be recreated at next user login without all the bloat.

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have any luck with reinstalling the [Windows Installer 4.5 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8483). Hopefully this doesn't become a chicken and egg deal where you can't install that because the installer doesn't work.

Comment: I downloaded that installer awhile ago and tried to install it but it said it wasn't supported or necessary on my system. Windows6.0-KB942288-v2-x86.msu is the one I tried (2008 32-bit).